# Open a third activity and start an action

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to develop an app to run in background and always that some specific apps start, my app takes some action, for example:

When Astro open my app must access Astro's menu and choose an option.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can not control apps in this manner. It would be a major security issue if you could.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to start your application depending on 3rd app.

But if the third app do specials things (take picture, take video, make call...or lot of ohter action) you can set a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen on Android actions.